# Utilizar función dentro de GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Tengo una lista de todos los accesos de cada empleado, cada día de la semana.
Necesito un reporte por empleado, por día de la semana, con la primera hora en que llegó a la oficina.

```
SELECT u.IDUser, u.FullName, GROUP_CONCAT(c.AccessTime ORDER BY c.AccessTime ASC SEPARATOR "|") AS AccessTime
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN checking c ON (c.IsUser = 1 AND c.UserOrClientID = u.IDUser) 
WHERE c.AccessTime BETWEEN '2022-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2022-07-15 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY u.IDUser ORDER BY u.FullName ASC;
```

Estoy obteniendo esto:

```
IDUser  FullName    AccessTime
230     Juan Perez  2022-07-01 06:25:25|2022-07-01 06:40:34|2022-07-01 06:54:20|2022-07-02 06:11:47|2022-07-02 08:10:01| ...
560     Ivan García 2022-07-01 15:28:50|2022-07-01 16:01:40|2022-07-02 15:12:40|2022-07-02 19:30:51| ...
```

Pero mi expectativa es esta:

```
IDUser  FullName    AccessTime
230     Juan Perez  2022-07-01 06:25:25|2022-07-02 06:11:47| ...
560     Ivan García 2022-07-01 15:28:50|2022-07-02 15:12:40| ...
```

O sea, el GROUP_CONCAT debería reportarme sólo los valores mínimos diarios y no todos los valores. Intenté poniendo la función MIN() dentro del GROUP_CONCAT y me da error.
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> el GROUP_CONCAT debería reportarme sólo los valores mínimos diarios y
> no todos los valores

`GROUP_CONCAT()` simplemente concatena la columna que recibe, y lo que le estas pasando son todos los `AccessTime` y lo que te falta en realidad es tener solo el `MIN(AccessTime)` de cada día, para obtenerlo puedes hacer algo asi:

```
SELECT u.IDUser, 
       u.FullName,
       DATE(c.AccessTime) as AccessTimeDate,
       MIN(c.AccessTime)  as MinAccessTime
       FROM users u 
       LEFT JOIN checking c 
            ON (c.IsUser = 1 AND c.UserOrClientID = u.IDUser) 
       WHERE c.AccessTime BETWEEN '2022-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2022-07-15 23:59:59' 
       GROUP BY u.IDUser, 
                u.FullName,
                DATE(c.AccessTime);
```

Teniendo ahora sí un solo `AccessTime` por fecha, puedes aplicar el `GROUP_CONCAT()` usando una subconsulta:

```
SELECT T.IDUser,
       T.FullName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(T.MinAccessTime ORDER BY T.MinAccessTime ASC SEPARATOR "|") AS AccessTime
       FROM (SELECT u.IDUser, 
                    u.FullName,
                    DATE(c.AccessTime) as AccessTimeDate,
                    MIN(c.AccessTime)  as MinAccessTime
                    FROM users u 
                    LEFT JOIN checking c 
                         ON (c.IsUser = 1 AND c.UserOrClientID = u.IDUser) 
                    WHERE c.AccessTime BETWEEN '2022-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2022-07-15 23:59:59' 
                    GROUP BY u.IDUser, 
                             u.FullName,
                             DATE(c.AccessTime)
        ) T
        GROUP BY T.IDUser,
                 T.FullName;
```

Comment: Gracias! Es exactamente lo que buscaba! Excelente!